UrlRequest is HTML Casing the JSON being delivered to server? (Spring Boot)
Recently, I have started working on my own PET project in iOS.
The task that I have at hand is as follows:

Serialize object into JSON using JSONEncoder
Deliver that JSON to server (Spring Boot)
Receive the response from that server
etc. etc.

I am using a standard JSONEncoder with couple of settings (see below):
JSON Encoding part
// Serializing it to the JSON
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .withoutEscapingSlashes
jsonEncoder.dataEncodingStrategy = .deferredToData
self.outSyncPackage = try jsonEncoder.encode(outSyncPackageObj)
let jsonStringToBeDelivered = String(data: self.outSyncPackage!, encoding: .utf8)

As per screenshot below, you can see that there are no issues there:
Encoded JSON Text
Then, I am creating a URLRequest, in order to deliver that JSON to the server:
Preparation of the URLRequest object for execution
self.urlRequest?.httpMethod = "POST"
 self.urlRequest?.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
//        self.urlRequest?.setValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Encoding")
self.urlRequest?.setValue(self.sessionId, forHTTPHeaderField: "sessionId")
self.urlRequest?.setValue(String(self.lastSyncDate), forHTTPHeaderField: "lastSyncDateTime")
self.urlRequest?.setValue(self.purchaseKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "subCode")
// Body
self.urlRequest?.httpBodyStream = InputStream(data: self.outSyncPackage!)

On the server side I expect the same JSON, with escape characters or not.
However, upon execution of this routine I get garbage on the server side as input JSON:
Outcome of the UrlRequest on the server side
Can somebody, please, explain to me what is it that I am doing wrong and why JSON is scrambled upon receipt?
Actual Result:
%7B%22accountCurrencyEntities%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22transactionTemplateEntities%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22serverRequestedReSync%22%3Afalse%2C%22currencyEntities%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22categoryEntities%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22webServerConfigurationEntities%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22transactionEntities%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22accountEntities%22%3A%5B%5D%7D=

Expected Result:
{"accountCurrencyEntities":[],"transactionTemplateEntities":[],"serverRequestedReSync":false,"currencyEntities":[],"categoryEntities":[],"webServerConfigurationEntities":[],"transactionEntities":[],"accountEntities":[]}

PS. I tried a lot of ways of decoding that resultant string, and I found out, that the text is actually 'HTTP URLed' somehow (see the Кодирование URL section on the screenshot):
Various encodings, including HTML Escape

You are receiving percent escaped JSON. I guess it's easy to remove the percent escaping (that's the keyword to look for instead of "HTTP URLed") from the server side. I don't know if it's normal or if it's an parameter on the server side

That’s the rub - I have already onboarded an Android application, and it sends a clean result. No percent escaped JSONs, no backslashes, no nothing. And from iOS I am receiving that percent escaped thingy which I don’t even know how to decode.

Have you tried using:
self.urlRequest?.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")

It worked! I forgot the Content-Type header and Spring Boot was interpreting it as god knows what, not the JSON! Thank you! Kudos!

I forgot to ask, but since it was working on Android what was the code? It could have help for comparison, and I guess that that missing header was in Android code but not here.

@Larme I can paste it here is you want to see it. There, it had a steaming implementation where content-type was mandatory and was specified in a different place, not within request, that’s okHttp library implementation, and that’s why I missed it.

Here is the code in Android for the request body:
        val outboundPackageBody: RequestBody = object : RequestBody() {
            override fun contentType(): MediaType {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
            }

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
                sink.writeUtf8(outSyncPackage)
            }
        }

